# Groovy v3 method reference and groovyString dynamic variable resolution priority if you explicitly set the MethodClosure delegate

Tags: groovy, method-reference

I am using Groovy v3.0.1.

I am seeing a response I had not expected from the following code.  I build a map of verb, noun and closures.

The first time I use the methodReference `mybed::trySleep` as the closure to be passed, but set the delegate to be the data object, and use DELEGATE_ONLY resolution.

The second entry passes a straight closure in line as the closure.

```
package playpen

class Bed {
    String name
    String bedSize = "5ft by 6ft"

    static sTrySleep () {
        println "called static on sleep"
    }

    void trySleep (arg = null) {
        println "called instance.onSleep() for name (${->name}) with " + arg ?: "<no arg>"
    }


}

Bed mybed = new Bed(name:"wills bed")

class DataObject {
    String name = "first data object"
    int height = 10
    int length = 12
    int width = 5
}

Map verbNounLookup = new HashMap()

Map buildAction (Map vnl, String verb, String noun, data, Closure method) {
    method.delegate = data
    method.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    def lookup = [(verb): [(noun): method]]
    vnl.putAll(lookup)
    lookup
}

buildAction (verbNounLookup, "go", "snooze", new DataObject(), mybed::trySleep)
buildAction (verbNounLookup, "do", "thing", new DataObject(), {println "called with $it, and sees name as: $name"})

def action = verbNounLookup.go.'snooze'

action ("hi")

action = verbNounLookup.do.thing
action( "william")
```

I had imagined for the first lookup that as the method reference builds its GString dynamically using {->name}, but the method's delegate has been overridden to my data object, that calling this method would resolve name on the data object as the new delegate.

The second entry which is my inline closure resolves name on the delegate data object as you'd expect.

It doesn't - it resolves name on the myBed instance instead.  Is this correct behavior?

Output is:

```
called instance.onSleep() for name (wills bed) with hi 
called with william, and sees name as: first data object
```

Comment: I see the same thing on Groovy 2.5.9 and `mybed.&trySleep` instead of `mybed::trySleep` so I assume this is the correct behavior

Answer (score 0):

MethodClosures don't use the delegate, they're a pointer to a method, and just invoke the method straight

(From [this post on the mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/MethodClosure-can-t-see-delegate-td5712726.html))

> A MethodClosure is like a "pointer" to a group of methods of the given
>   name for the given instance. The delegate doesn't play any role in
>   this. Even if it would, once you enter the method, the normal rules of
>   that method apply. And that means that the method resolving process is
>   done by the meta class of the class the method is defined in